# Can timer run in Background Task

Tags: winrt-xaml, uwp

say I have 3 pages: P1, P2 and P3

User can navigate P1 -> P2 -> P3

At P3 , I need a timer that keep running and it trigger to call a function at certain interval.
say, the timer will call a function in every one minute interval.

```
1) Timer function:

tick = 60;

if (_fixedTick > 0)
{
    _fixedTick--;
}
else
{
 call a func();

}
```

The problem:

- If user navigate from P3 to P2 , this will stop the timer.

I come across the background Task

Question

a)How to build a timer which will call a function at a fixed interval. ie: Tick =60. 
b) Is above (1) Timer function a good way to handle timing?

C) Can some1 show me how to create a background Timer in Background Task.
can use Above (1) Timer function in Background Task so that the timer will keep running whether user navigate from P3 to P2.

```
namespace MyTimerTask
{
    public sealed class FirstTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {


        }
    }
```

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: You can use TimeTrigger or MaintenanceTrigger (if you device is plugged to AC/DC) Read this article:
[Create and register a background task that runs in a separate process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task)

Answer (score 0):

No, a background task is not the way to go. Just create a simple `DispatcherTimer` in some global location like a static class, static property on App.xaml.cs, etc.

Comment: Is the simple Timer function with Tick OK base on DispatcherTimer? Can u show me one that run in App.Xaml.cs? thanks

Comment: we are not here to write code for you, just to help and guide you

Comment: So where to place this timer func code in App.Xaml.cs? At Lunch Event ? I will write one myself. Do you mean in this App.xaml.cs will allow the timer run even the user navigate P3 to P2? Do you think using Tick-- is ok?

Comment: Of course, providing code samples is part of SO. I can only disagree.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

### Page3.xaml.cs

```
public Page3()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I hope this helps.